# Select all but one td in a table using CSS

Tags: css

I’m looking for a way to style everything except some. If I wanted to select everything within a table except a particular td how to achieve this using css only ?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail and html in question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your particular td has a class name then:

```
table td { background: red; }
table td.particular { background: white; } /* inherit, auto, etc */
```

Answer (score 1):

there are several way to do that. For example

give common property

```
table tr td{background:red}
```

for particular element

```
table tr td:nth-child(3){background:green};
```

there other `:last-child, :first-child`

Answer (score 1):

There's also a :not() pseudo class in CSS3 which does similar thing.Here is the working demo too http://jsfiddle.net/raynesax/Ps48t/1/